# How can I use a variable that points to a table in clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
DECLARE @myTable = [database].[dbo].[MyTable]

INSERT INTO @myTable () VALUES ()
SELECT * FROM @myTable
DELETE FROM @myTable
```

Can this be done?

Comment: Look into using `dynamic sql`.

Comment: fyi: Accepting answers is part of the etiquette at StackOverflow. See [How Does Accepting An Answer Work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use dynamic SQL.  And worse, you can't even pass the table as a parameter:

```
DECLARE @myTable NVARCHAR(MAX) = '[database].[dbo].[MyTable]';

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'INSERT INTO [myTable](. . .) VALUES (. . .)';

SET @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL, '[myTable]', @myTable);

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```